# OPENCART: How to edit the checkout process

Tags: opencart

I am starting to develop a store for a client in Opencart, and he wants to change the checkout process so that instead of completing the checkout process, the customer gets a note saying that the order must be completed over the phone. (This makes sense in the context of this specific store.)

Any ideas on how to do that? Which templates/files would I be editing in the back-end? Is there a way to do this in the front-end?

Comment: Sounds like you could just the "Cash on delivery" payment option (disable all the others if you don't want to accept credit cards at all), and then create/modify some verbiage, either in checkout.tpl, catalog/language/en-gb/checkout/checkout.php or /catalog/language/en-gb/payment/cod.php

Comment: @LucasKrupinski You should add this as an answer; that would be my suggestion too.